# After binding Mac to AD, first login successfully creates mobile account and logs in, after that next login locks AD account

Tags: macos, active-directory

Configuration: Mac OS X 10.7 and 10.8 Active Directory Server 2008 R2 Binding using AD Plugin or `dsconfigad -add mydomain -username myuser -ou "OU=Computers,OU=Sites,OU=Mysite,DC=mycompany,DC=com"`

Works fine. First login happens fine. Creates mobile account, no issues noticed.

However, after I logout, the next login attempt fails, and after only shaking one time, their AD account is locked out.

`opendirectory.log` makes a vague mention of account being expired but honestly I don't see much in the logs that pops out as useful.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the AD plugin from Centrify which worked fine.  I have abandoned the Apple plugin until they get their act together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would the network time server have anything to do with it? Sometimes password reset events can cause locks due to the old credentials being rejected as multiple devices hit AD, but these are new accounts? You can turn up logging on the client, and even tail the logs in realtime over ssh if you'd like less vague of a picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I recently had a similar experience with 10.8 and 10.8 Server with Open Directory.

We applied a global policy to NOT have passwords expire (there's a bug where it defaults to expiring shortly after the account is created).  That wasn't enough however: I then had to delete and re-create all of the OpenDirectory accounts.  Smooth sailing after that.

I'm wondering if you're experiencing the same thing in AD.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be (in order of likelihood):

1. AD is creating the account with a one-time-use password: Make sure to change the password upon successfully logging in for the first time.
2. A domain prefix might be required: OS X can be configured to imply the account's domain name, or explicitly require the account's domain name. Examples:

   1. A username with an implied domain name: *username*
   2. A username with an explicit domain name: *DOMAIN\username* or *username@fully.qualified.domain.name*
3. Time drift between AD server and Mac client: Make sure the sure the two machines are synched to the same time server.